# How to integrate angular2-datatable with angularfire2 observable array

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

Hi I'm trying to implement angular2-datatable for my Angular 2 app, but I have a question: How can I pass de array info from angularfire2 observable to the data-table?, here is an image of the example they use and my explanation :

[image]

So my question is how do I replace mf.data for items in the *ngFor sentence?
Thanks in advance for any tip.

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to the observable.

```
let data = af2.db.list('/data').subscribe(
    (elems) => {
      this.data = elems;
    }
);
```